# Why button fits the entire screen and how can I move the segmented control to the top of the screen

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode6

I have the following view:

[image]

And I need to add button to the top right part of the screen, but when I try to drag and drop it I see the following:

[image]

Why does it fits the entire screen? How can I fix it?

And the second question -- how can I move the segmented control to the top of the screen (before `UITableView` in this case)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot see any place for your button. The tableview is taking all place on the screen. Just make it smaller and then place button/segment controller to proper place.

Comment: @Viktor Kucera What is the proper way to make it smaller? I don't think that the explicit size is the better solution

Comment: You can set up table size you want. There is no rule about it. But I am just wondering if you didn't placed tableview controller instead of viewcontroller + tableview on storyboard. Do you feel the difference?

Comment: @Viktor Kucera No. What is the difference?

Comment: Basically when you want to have some table along with other objects like segment controll, other tableview, buttons..you would use uiviewcontroller and drag&drop all other needed objects. Uitableviewcontroller (which you used) don't give you such flexibility. I ralely use uitableviewcontroller. Like never:).